# Convergent subsequence - Optimization

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, optimization

Let $f$ be a continuous and strictly convex $function$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\lim_{\lvert x \rvert \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$$

Let $K$ be a non-empty convex closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\psi$ be a continuous function of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $K=\psi^{-1}(0)$. Let $f_k$ be such that $f_k(x)=f(x)+k\psi(x)$.

I've already proved that there exists a unique minimizer $\overline{x}_k$ of $f_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_K$ a unique minimizer $x_K \in K$ of $f$ in $K$. Finally, I have proved that:

$$f(\overline{x}_k) \leq f_k(\overline{x}_k) \leq f(\overline{x}_K).$$

I have to show that there exists a subsequence $(x_{k_n})_n$ and $y \in K$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \overline{x}_{k_n}=y$. Any hints or ideas? I thought about Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for compact sets but I don't think it applies here.

Comment: Surely you need more conditions on $\psi$? What if you choose $\psi=0$?

Comment: If I choose $\psi(x)=0$, that means that $x \in K$. So $f_k(x)=f(x)$. @copper.hat

Comment: If I choose $\psi(x)=0$, that means that $x \in K$. So $f_k(x)=f(x)$. @copper.hat

Comment: Are you saying that $K = \psi^{-1}( \{0 \})$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes